# bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: linux, bash, debian

While this may be the same question as others have asked with the same issue I am hoping someone can help me out regardless as I am out of my depth.

I have a Seedhost server with Swizzin installed which has worked perfectly for a month but today I am getting errors that I have no clue how to fix.

rtorrent seems to be running perfectly in screen after restarting the server but rutorrent returns

```
Bad response from server: (0 [error,getplugins])
```

When trying to use tab to complete a path it returns

```
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

df shows

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G   17M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/md126      118G  118G     0 100% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md2       1008M   94M  864M  10% /boot
/dev/md127       15T  3.8T  9.8T  28% /home
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Your dir is full. Make some space there. Clear out old logs.

Comment: Well, / is full. Time to clean up and delete some files.

Comment: Thank you both, that fixed the issue. This is somewhat of a learning curve. Is there a way to allow more space for logs without reinstalling everything?

Comment: It seems Artillery is filling the user.log with many detections per second, making it a huge file, Fixing that should solve the issue.

Comment: 118G is a very very very big `/` (root) partition. What do you have on it?

Comment: user.log is 36GB, virtually all the content is Artillery claiming it is detecting incoming
connection from 127.0.0.1. multiple times per second. I'll change the size limit in logrotate which will resolve it for now and take it up with the Artillery devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is logging, then you can look at log rotation, to compress old logs, and remove very old logs. You system should already have it, but it may need configuring for the log that is growing very fast.